# Difference in differences to estimate differential impact of treatment?

Tags: econometrics, causality, estimators, difference-in-difference, heterogeneity

I'm having some trouble thinking through the implementation of difference-in-differences / if DD is the best approach to use when I am comparing two groups who are both treated, but which I hypothesize are affected differently by a particular policy.

I am studying the impacts of a particular educational policy (the "treatment") on people's enrollment in a specified school program. I hypothesize that, as a result of the policy, white students enrolled in these school programs more than black students did, even though both groups were technically exposed to the "treatment".

I have school-level data (% of black, white students enrolled in the program in the year before and after the policy, number of students at the school, etc.). I was planning on using the classic DD specification with Post, White, and Post x White variables, weighted by school size and with school district fixed effects.

However, I'm getting tripped up because the classic DD formulation requires the assumption that the control group is untreated. In my case, both of the groups are treated, but I am trying to estimated the differential impact of the policy on one group compared to another. Is there a way to do this empirically? Any help, ideas, or insights would be much appreciated -- thank you so so much!